# Dagster+dbt : referring a dagster asset as a source in dbt model

Tags: dagster

my dbt_model’s source is a dasgter asset out of dbt, how can I refer this asset inside a dbt model definiton?

the dagster asset =

```
@asset(
    group_name=". .... ",
    io_manager_key="..   ",
)
def dld_sales():
```

dbt model =

```
with source as (
    select * from {{ ref("dld_sales") }}
),
```

gives me error:

```
Model ‘model.dbt_project.stg_dld_sales’ (models/staging/stg_dld_sales.sql) depends on a node named ‘dld_sales’ which was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` can only be used for models that dbt is aware of. dbt is not aware of assets materialized by dagster so you can't use a `ref` call.

You need to define the dagster-materialized asset in dbt as a source in a .yml file and call it like so:

```
with source as (
    select * from {{ source("<source name>", ""dld_sales") }}
),
```